# How to write SQL Expression for Ingres Database in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I am building a Crystal Report from Ingres Database that I only need the last 7 for. I am hoping that instead of having to generate all 1000+ records for 800+ vehicle, I can write an SQL statement something to the effect of:

```
SELECT "trigger_readings"."facility_code", "trigger_readings"."trigger_reading", "trigger_readings"."reading_date"
FROM "trigger_readings"
LIMIT 7
```

However, when trying this i get an error message from crystal saying:

> Error in compiling SQL Expression:
>   Database Connector Error: '5000A:[CA][Ingres ODBC Driver][Ingres]line 1, FROM clause is mandatory when a column('select') has been specified in the target list. [Database Vendor Code: 2103]'

Is there a way that I can achieve this without the SQL expression in Crystal Reports? If not, how do I fix the sql statement?

**EDIT:** Am looking for the most recent records by date (just to clarify)

Comment: Have you tried removing the carriage returns from the statement, so that it is all on one line? The error message makes it look as though the driver isn't seeing the FROM clause.

Comment: Does the SQL statement work in a query tool?

Comment: Banister: Have tried that. Same result
craig: I have tried using Query Tool in Excel 2007 through ODBC connection which works when getting data from 1 table, but crashes the query tool whenever i try to link tables, hence trying the Crystal Approach

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Ingres are you using?  The error message suggests you might be using a very old release from Computer Associates (CA).  Be warned that may be difficult.  It can be done and I'll give the code for it if you need it.  All current versions use the SELECT FIRST n syntax.

You say you want the last 7.  Is that the last seven rows?  Sorted by date?  i.e. the most recent 7 rows?

Try this:

```
SELECT FIRST 7 tr.facility_code, tr.trigger_reading, tr.reading_date 
FROM trigger_readings tr 
ORDER BY tr.reading_date DESC;
```

Comment: Hi quelgeek tried your solution to no avail, still get the same message, even if i put it all on one line. The ingres version we are using is 2.6 (the software interfacing it was built in the early 90's, so the DB is likely to be equally old).
Sorry for the lack of clarity. Your right i do want the most recent 7 rows. Many thanks!

Comment: If you could provide that you mentioned previously for the old release that would be fantastic, currently my workaround must be run overnight due to the high likelyhood of crashing the server.